# What is wrong with the following alleged derivations?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

a.

1. $(\exists x )B(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad \text{Hyp}$
2. $B(d) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{1,rule C}$
3. $(\exists x) C(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{Hyp}$
4. $C(d)\quad \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad \text{3,rule C}$
5. $B(d) \land C(d) \quad \quad \quad\text{2,4 conjuction introduction} $
6. $(\exists x)( B(x) \land C(x)) \quad \text{5,rule E4}$
7. $(\exists x) B(x), (\exists x )C(x) \vdash  (\exists x )(B(x) \land C(x)) \quad \text{1-6 Proposition 2.10}$

b.

1. $(\exists x )(B(x) \Rightarrow C(x)) \quad \quad\text{Hyp}$
2. $(\exists x )B(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{Hyp}$
3. $(B(d) \Rightarrow C(d)) \quad \quad  \text{1,rule C}$
4. $B(d) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\text{2,rule C}$
5. $C(d) \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\text{3,4 MP} $
6. $(\exists x) C(x) \quad  \quad \quad \quad\text{5,rule E4}$
7. $(\exists x )(B(x) \Rightarrow C(x)), (\exists x )B(x) \vdash  (\exists x) C(x) \quad \text{1-6 Proposition 2.10}$

Proposition 2.10:
If $\Gamma \vdash_C B,$ then $ \Gamma \vdash B $

In (a) I see that in **step 4**, b is not a new individual constant. It was already used in step 2. Thus therefore (a) is wrong.

In (b), I think **Rule E4** in **step 6** can not be used because d is not free for x. Is this a correct argument?

Or can you not apply **MP** in **step 5**? If this is so, why can you not apply Modus ponens in step 5?

Answer (score 3):

Step 4 is wrong: there is no reason to assume that existing object being $B$ - called $d$ - is the same that the existing object being $C$ - called also $d$.

The error is the same in both derivations. In b. you assume that $B(d) \to C(d)$ holds for a unspecified object $d$. But the conditional is true also when $C(d)$ holds and $B(d)$ does not. So, you are not entitled to assume that $B(d)$ holds; you need a **new** term.